# Jenkins - cleanup after job

Tags: jenkins, hudson

I have a couple of unit testing / BDD jobs on our Jenkins instance that trigger a bunch of processes as they run. I have multiple Windows slaves, any one of which can run my tests.

After the text execution is complete, irrespective of the build status is passed/failed/unstable, I want to run "taskkill" and kill a couple of processes.

I had been doing that earlier by triggering a "Test_Janitor" downstream job - but this approach doesn't work anymore since I added more than one slave.

How can I either run the downstream job on the same slave as the upstream, or have some sort of a post build step to run "taskkill".

Comment: Well, when a builds ends, all processes started during that build should be killed. Isn't it the case for you?

Comment: @StéphaneBruckert Nope, looks like the processes continue running.. I have to manually kill it on the box to avoid the job from erroring out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the [Post Build Task](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task) plugin to call a batch script on the slave (when your UT/BDD are completed).

The other solution is to call a downstream job and to pass the %NODE_NAME% variable to this job with the [Parameterized Trigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) plugin.

Next, you can use [psexec](http://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html) to kill the processes on the relevant node.